# HTML numerical to UTF

Tags: html, utf

How can i convert this

$langClarContent = >
&# 1059.,&#1095.,&#1080.,&# 1090.,&# 1077.,&# 1083.,Dokeos &# 1077., &# 1089.,&# 1080.,&# 1089.,&# 1090.,&# 1077.,&# 1084., &# 1079.,&# 1072.,  &# 1091.,&# 1087.,&# 1088.,&# 1072.,&# 1074.,&# 1091.,&# 1074.,&# 1072.,&# 1114.,&#1077., &# 1089.,&#1086., &# 1091.,&# 1095.,&# 1077.,&# 1114.,&# 1077., &# 1080., &# 1079.,&# 1085.,&# 1072.,&#1077.,&# 1114.,&# 1077.,. &# 1058.,&# 1086.,&# 1112., &# 1080.,&#1084., &# 1076.,&# 1086.,&# 1087.,&# 1091.,&# 1096.,&# 1090.,&# 1072., &# 1085.,&# 1072., &#1091.,&# 1095

to an utf related answer like

$langClarContent = Учител Dokeos е систем за управување со учење и знаење. Тој им допушта на у&#1095

Comment: Are you working in PHP (I'm guessing by the `$`)? If not, what language or framework are you using?

Comment: Well yea i am using php, but the language doesent matter ill use every langugae that does the bidding, i have a file with  loads of HTML codes i want them in utf. I like the answer below, i'll just write a script doing for all files and for all codes and it should work, the only problem is where can i find the codes to utf equivalent list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note.. `Htmlspecialchar` only converts some of the characters.. if you want to convert all characters use: `html_entity_decode`

http://th.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

Once you have that array properly formatted you can do something like this in PHP:

```
foreach ($langClarContent as $char){
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($char);
}
```

Comment: Thanks,
this helps a lot, didnt solved my problem fully, but helps enough to solve it :D.
Thanks a lot.
i have a file full of htmlcodes, i wish to create the same file but with the utf twins inside it...